# How to change the icon and text for Places ("Application Links") in IFileDialog?

Tags: windows

I have a custom Open File Dialog that uses IFileDialog. I use AddPlace to add a link (with custom text) to a folder of sample files that we provide with our application. So far, so good. It looks like this: 
[My custom file dialog with a generic "Application Links" section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzCtK.png)

I would like to customize the "Application Links" node itself with my own text and icon. [Visual Studio does this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK7F1.png) It looks like Word tries, too.

Any idea how I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am currently encountering the same problem, but in a more complicated manner. Fortunately for you, I found the solution for your problem.

The executable file of your project simply needs to have a "version info" resource.
The text of "FileDescription" will be used for the top node (which is currently "Application Links"). The icon seems to be the icon of the executable (which is also part of the file's resources).

The "version info" is described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Simply include such a resource to your application exe file.

Comment: Before I forget: This behavior seems to be undocumented.